# Azuma inequality with probabilistic bound for the increments

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, concentration-of-measure

Let $(X_i)$ be a super-martingale and suppose their differences are bounded ''with high probability'', that is
$$\mathbb{P}(\exists\,i=1,\dots,n\text{ s.t. }|X_i-X_{i-1}|>c_i) \,\leq\, \epsilon$$
for suitable constants $(c_i)$ and $\epsilon>0$.
I read that for all $t>0$
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n>X_0+t) \,\leq\, \exp\big(-\frac{t^2}{2\,\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2}\big) +\,\epsilon\;.$$

How can I prove this result? I already know that it holds for $\epsilon=0$ (it is called Azuma-Hoeffding inequality), but I don't manage to deduce this corollary.
My first idea was to split and bound the probability as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X_0|<t) \,\leq\, \mathbb{P}(|X_n-X_0|<t \ \big|\ \forall\,i=1,\dots,n\,|X_i-X_{i-1}|\leq c_i) \,+\, \epsilon$$
but then I don't know how to bound the first term on the r.h.s. because I don't know if $(X_i)$ is still a super-martingale with respect to the conditional probability.

Answer (score 0):

The question received two answers at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171479/extension-of-the-azuma-hoeffding-inequality-when-the-differences-are-bounded-wi), pointing out several helpful references.